# MongoDB tweet hashtags coincidence count

Tags: mongodb, twitter, mapreduce

I have some tweets downloaded to my mongodb.
The tweet document looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong("542499449474273280"),
    "retweeted" : false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-12-10T02:02:02Z"),
    "hashtags" : [
       "Canucks",
       "allhabs",
       "GoHabsGo"
    ]
    ...
}
```

I want a construct a query/aggregation/map-reduce that will give me the count of tweets that have the same two hash tags. For every pair of nonequal hashtags it gives me the count of tweets eg.:

```
{'count': 12, 'pair': ['malaria', 'Ebola']}
{'count': 1, 'pair': ['Nintendo', '8bit']}
{'count': 1, 'pair': ['guinea', 'Ebola']}
{'count': 1, 'pair': ['fitness', 'HungerGames']}
...
```

I've made a `python` script to do this:

```
hashtags = set()

tweets = db.tweets.find({}, {'hashtags':1})
#gather all hashtags from every tweet
for t in tweets:
    hashtags.update(t['hashtags'])

hashtags = list(hashtags)

hashtag_count = []
for i, h1 in enumerate(hashtags):
    for j, h2 in enumerate(hashtags):
        if i > j:
            count = db.tweets.find({'hashtags' : {'$all':[h1,h2]}}).count()
            if count > 0:
                pair = {'pair' : [h1, h2], 'count' : count}
                print(couple)
                db.hashtags_pairs.insert(pair)
```

But I want to make it just with a query or `JS` functions to use the map-reduce.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's no aggregation pipeline or query that can compute this from your given document structure, so you'll have to use map/reduce if you don't want to drastically change the collection structure or construct a secondary collection. The map/reduce, however, is straightforward: in the map phase, emit a pair `(pair of hashtags, 1)` for each pair of hashtags in the document, then sum the values for each key in the reduce phase.

```
var map = function() { 
    var tags = this.tags;
    var k = tags.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
            if (tags[i] != tags[j]) { 
                var ts = [tags[i], tags[j]].sort(); 
                emit({ "t0" : ts[0], "t1" : ts[1] }, 1) 
            }
        }
    }
}

var reduce = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values) }
```